# Unknown provider: uiCropperProvider <- uiCropper

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I am trying to work on image crop functionality and using "https://www.npmjs.com/package/ui-cropper" library.

But when i am integrating into my code, it's keep on throwing error Unknown provider: uiCropperProvider <- uiCropper

Here is my controller

```
 (function () {
  'use strict';

  // Widgets controller
  angular
  .module('widgets')
  .controller('EditWidgetController', EditWidgetController);

  EditWidgetController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', '$window', 'Authentication', 'WidgetsService', '$firebaseStorage', '$firebaseAuth', 'UsersService', 'Upload', 'FirebaseService', 'Notification', '$base64', 'widgetResolve', '$stateParams', '$firebaseArray', '$interval', 'uiCropper'];

  function EditWidgetController($scope, $rootScope, $state, $window, Authentication, WidgetsService, $firebaseStorage, $firebaseAuth, UsersService, Upload, FirebaseService, Notification, $base64, widget, $stateParams, $firebaseArray, $interval, uiCropper) {
```

here i have defined the library path

[image]

Error i am getting:

[image]

Please suggest me how can i overcome with this error. It's eating my head :(

Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: i didn't understand. I am new to angular. can you send me what should i do.. you mean to say, widget "$base64, widget, $stateParams," this middle widget is missing ?

Comment: Basha, Can you confirm that you have injected `['uiCropper']` in the `mainApp` module ?

Comment: if i remove uiCropper, it's working fine.. but i need this image crop feature. @ShashankVivek

Comment: Have you done `angular.module('app', ['uiCropper'])`  ?? Share that code in your que where you have injected it

Comment: I cant find `angular.module` anywhere in that file. Can you share the file which has it ? This file is not what initializes the `angular` app

Comment: Updated my  question with code : (function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('widgets')
  .controller('EditWidgetController', EditWidgetController);

Comment: can you come in teamviewer or anydesk application so that i can share my screen with you ?

Comment: this file is not `module` initilizer. diff is module initilizer have `angular.module('widgets',[])` . Try to find "**angular.module('widgets',[** " keyword in js file and let me know here.

Comment: angular
    .module('widgets')
    .controller('CreateWidgetController', CreateWidgetController);

  CreateWidgetController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$window', 'Authentication', 'WidgetsService', '$firebaseStorage', '$firebaseAuth', 'UsersService', 'Upload', 'FirebaseService', 'Notification', '$base64', '$stateParams'];

Comment: I cant some teamviewer right now, May be we can come on chat. The `controller ` you are providing is not the main js file. The main js file will have square bracket `[ ]` inside `angular.module`.  Search for a file with -->  **angular.module('widgets',[** and provide that

Comment: i don't have enough reputation to come on chat.. Can u come in skype atleast ?

Comment: Can you try https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171456/basha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above conversation, I can suggest you to check for the file with `angular.module('widgets', [])`, and inject `uiCropper` inside it as DI.

```
angular.module('widgets', ['uiCropper' , 'Some_other_modules']) // <-- Try this injection of `uiCropper`
```

Note:

`angular.module('widgets', []).controller()` is different from `angular.module('widgets').controller()`. The difference is that with `[ ]` , you are basically declaring the `angular module`.

[Play around in this plunkr to get the idea.](https://plnkr.co/edit/lfvQJcCWxmAFnGgtzmpK?p=preview) Not that `app.js` has
 `angular.module('plunker', [])` where as `other.js` has `angular.module('plunker')`. Also, check the sequence of files which are included in `index.html`. The declaration file comes before the others

Comment: can u please rate my question to increase my reputation please.

Comment: @Basha : Rated two ;)